# Error Installing Scrapy on Mac OSX 10.9.2

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, portia

I've been getting the following error whenever I try to install the required packages for a scrapy-backed python project.

```
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hqp6xc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/MichaelBoydBrowne/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I've tried installing using sudo and that hasn't worked. Let me know what could be wrong. If it's any help I've been getting similar errors from other python-based installations I've tried to do to remedy the problem.

Comment: Seems like the useful error messages could be above where you pasted from... I could be wrong though, may be worth a second look

Answer (score 2):

You may not have your xcode command line tools. Try running this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```